# Java springframework: transaction semantics

Tags: spring, transactionscope

In spring framework, there is transaction semantics: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_ONLY. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about [Spring Transactions in the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

You are specifically asking about Transaction Propagation, which is section 10.5.7 of the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you will find all isolation levels and types of propagation managed by the latest version of Spring :
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html

"ISOLATION_ONLY" is not part of it.

Answer (score 1):

See JavaDoc for [TransactionDefinition](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html), it describes all propagation behaviors in great detail.

In short `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` means that a given method requires a transaction to run. If it is run from within an existing transaction, it will join it. If there is no transaction in the current execution thread, the container will create one for you and commit when you leave the method.

I have never heard about `ISOLATION_ONLY`, where have you seen it?

See also:

- [EJB3 Transaction Propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106437)